# Tikz: keys appending label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there a (short) solution, so that a label is defined by multiple keys?

I guess one solution could be using if-statements (I'm not sure if this is possible).

An other solution could be something like (I'm unsure about the line breaks...):

```
\tikzset{%
 mylabel/.style = {label={[red]right:{}}},%
one/.style args = {#1}{mylabel.append(O:#1)},%
two/.style args = {#1}{mylabel.append(T:#1)}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
one/.style args = {#1}{label={[red]right:O:#1}},%
two/.style args = {#1}{label={[red]right:T:#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,2) [draw,one=A] {};
\node at (0,1) [draw,two=B] {};
\node at (0,0) [draw,one=C,two=D] {}; %this should automatically look like below

\node at (0,-1) [draw,one=C,label={[red,yshift=-1em]right:T:D}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In order for this to work, Ti*k*Z would have to "know" that there is already a node at the position it wants to place the next one. Not sure if that's possible. Even if it is, I have strong feeling that the efforts will be much larger than shifting the nodes in the way you already do.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done using pgfkeys but TeX's syntax is more predictable.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\def\prepare{coordinate(X)}
\def\one#1{(X.south west)node(X)[right]{O:#1}}
\def\two#1{(X.south west)node(X)[right]{T:#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
    (0,2) node [draw] {} \prepare\one{A}
    (0,1) node [draw] {} \prepare\two{B}
    (0,0) node [draw] {} \prepare\one{A}\two{B} ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution (not very nice because use a global variable `\labelshift`):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=7pt, convert={density=2100}]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  checkbox/.style = {draw},
  checkbox/.append code={\xdef\labelshift{-1}},
  plus/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\labelshift{\labelshift+1}\xdef\labelshift{\labelshift}},
  next/.style={label={right,yshift=-\labelshift*4mm,plus:#1}},
  one/.style = {every label/.style=red,next={O:#1}},
  two/.style = {next={T:#1}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,2) [checkbox,one=A] {};
    \node at (0,1) [checkbox,two=B] {};
    \node at (0,0) [checkbox,one=C,two=D,one=E] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]